# Can we use login flows to display based specific criteria?

Tags: loginflow

Can we use login flows to display certain information only on 1st time login of a user. I want the user to accept some terms on first time login.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is one of the examples giving in the [official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Login-Flows).

Seems there is even a link to an unmanaged package to install different login flow samples into your org.